# Passing dynamic text value to shared button component in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vuex, vue-props

I'm trying to pass dynamic text value to my shared component named "Button component" whose text should appear in Spanish or English based on the language chosen.

For translation, I already have translation.service.js doing the conversions.
I'm not sure how to pass the value to the **:text** parameter below by using the service as the current format for **:text** is showing error. It's working fine elsewhere in p tags.
Any help/suggestion would be appreciated as I'm not able to move forward.

```
<Button 
          @on-click="currentStep = 1"
          :text= {{ this.getTranslation("intro_modal_persona_select_button_next") }}  
          bgColor="transparent"
          txtColor="#d64ba1"
/>
```

The full code in  is:

```
<template>
  <div class="d-flex mb-3 justify-content-between">
    <div class="p-2">
      <Logo :type="logoType" />
    </div>
    <div class="p-2">
      <ButtonIcon symbol="corner-down-left" :disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
    <!--Step 1: Language Selection-->

    <p class="step">{{ currentStep }} OF 2</p>
    <p class="community-name">
      {{  community.c_community_name}}
    </p>

    <div class="p-2 flex-fill" v-if="currentStep == 1">

      <VueScrollPicker 
        id="language-scroller"
        :options="options" 
        v-model="selectedLanguage"
      />

      <!--Language selection scroll-->
      <p class="option-select">
        {{ this.getTranslation("intro_modal_persona_select_language") }}
      </p>

      <div 
        v-if="selectedLanguage"
        class="button_container text-center"
      >
        <Button
          @on-click="currentStep = 2"
          :text= {{ this.getTranslation("intro_modal_persona_select_button_next") }} 
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--Step 2: Agent Selection-->
    <div class="p-2 flex-fill" v-if="currentStep == 2">

      <div id="persona-slider-wrapper" ref="persona_slider_wrapper">
        <PersonalSlider :personas="personas" />
      </div>
      <p class="option-select">
        {{ this.getTranslation("intro_modal_persona_select_agent") }}
      </p>

      <div 
        v-if="selectedLanguage"
        class="button_container text-center"
      >
        <Button 
          @on-click="goToDigitalHumanView"
          :text= {{ this.getTranslation("intro_modal_persona_select_button_begin") }} 
          class="mb-2"
        />

        <Button 
          @on-click="currentStep = 1"
          :text= {{ this.getTranslation("intro_modal_persona_select_button_back") }}   
          bgColor="transparent"
          txtColor="#d64ba1"
        />
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <MainFooter />
  </div>
</template>
```

My translation service:

```
class TranslationService {
    async loadTranslations() {
        return [
            // Intro Modal Persona Select
            {
                'key': 'intro_modal_persona_select_language',
                'en': 'Select your Language',
                'es': 'Elige tu Idioma'
            },

            {
                'key': 'intro_modal_persona_select_button_next',
                'en': 'Next',
                'es': 'Siguiente'
            },

            {
                'key': 'intro_modal_persona_select_agent',
                'en': "Select your agent",
                'es': 'Seleccione su agente'
            },

            {
                'key': 'intro_modal_persona_select_button_begin',
                'en': 'Begin',
                'es': 'Comenzar'
            },
          ];
    }
}

export default new TranslationService()
```

Answer (score 1):

Binding a value to a prop should be done like `v-bind:attr="value"` or `:attr="value"`, and handling events should be done in this way `v-on:click="eventHandler"` or `@click="eventHandler"`:

```html
<Button 
          @click="currentStep = 1"
          :text='getTranslation("intro_modal_persona_select_button_next")' 
          bgColor="transparent"
          txtColor="#d64ba1"
/>
```